# STM: estimating metadata/topic relationships when starting from dfm

Tags: r, metadata, topic-modeling, dfm

After running an **STM** model based on a **Quanteda dfm**, I want to estimate my covariates' effects on certain topics.

Running the STM model went fine, producing the topics as expected, but when using `estimateEffect` (in the final step in the script below) the R session is aborted, notifying there is a 'fatal error'.

How can I estimate my covariates' effects, when starting from a dfm? The STM manual advices on running an STM model from a dfm, but I couldn't find how to work with the covariates after this stage.

Here's the code:

```
# Read texts with Quanteda
texts <- (readtext("C:/Users/renswilderom/Documents/Stuff Im working on at the moment/Newspaper articles DJ/test data/*.txt",
         docvarsfrom = "filenames", dvsep = "_", 
         docvarnames = c("Date of Publication", "Length LexisNexis", "source"), 
         encoding = "UTF-8-BOM"))  

mycorpus <- corpus(texts)  

tokens <- tokens(mycorpus, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, ngrams = 1)

mydfm <- dfm(tokens, remove = stopwords("english"), stem = TRUE)


# Run the STM model - Metadata is called with 'data = docvars(mycorpus)'
stm_from_dfm <- stm(mydfm, K = 10, prevalence =~ Date.of.Publication + source, gamma.prior='L1', data = docvars(mycorpus)) 

# Estimate effects
prep <- estimateEffect(1:10 ~ Date.of.Publication + source, stm_from_dfm, 
                       meta = docvars(mycorpus), uncertainty = "Global")
```

Alternatively, I made an STM corpus from my dfm corpus, using `STMcorpus <- asSTMCorpus(mydfm)`. But then I couldn't run the STM model as it didn't recognized my meta data. Would it be better to follow this alternative strategy? (so I need to associate the meta data with the STMcorpus in some way after running `STMcorpus <- asSTMCorpus(mydfm)`).

Comment: It is hard to diagnose without a reproducible example- could you provide one? Also I think quanteda includes the data when you do `asSTMCorpus(mydfm)`.  The metadata is just the object in the list named `data`

Comment: Sure, here is a sample of the actual newspaper articles I'm using: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a50d8b8fd524359751e8aa68bac3256c20171016160720/3f3bb29e40362434594f44aeee1e67f720171016160720/b425d8 I'dd prefer to work from the `stm_from_dfm`, but if necessary, I can of course also work from the `asSTMCorpus(mydfm)`. I will just give it a try to access the metadata through the list `data`.

Comment: I was not able to replicate your error with the data sample you gave me.  If you want to share a copy of the workspace just before you call `estimateEffect()` I can try to replicate from there- but otherwise there isn't much I can do without being able to recreate the problem.

Comment: OK, thanks, yes I will share a copy of the workspace (will work on that now). And just to be sure, you used to code I posted above? (so, in other words, the code should be fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We worked through this by email- but I'll add the answer here for others who might encounter some form of the problem.

There is a bug in the `matrixStats` package which causes R to crash with large matrices on Windows only.  The bug and solution are detailed here: https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/matrixStats/issues/104. This issue contains both a simple test of the problem and instructions for how to install the development version of `matrixStats` which fixes it. This is an issue in version `matrixStats 0.52.2` and will presumably be resolved by the next CRAN release.